# JPG image size reduced on imsave

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am building up a library called [hips](http://hips.readthedocs.io/) where one module is involved with fetching tile images and storing them on disk. The problem here is that I fetch a tile from a [remote URL](http://alasky.unistra.fr/2MASS/H/Norder6/Dir30000/Npix30889.jpg) and save it using [scipy.misc.imsave](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html) function in a temporary directory. The saved file size is `41.0 kB`, however, if I save the file manually from the [remote URL](http://alasky.unistra.fr/2MASS/H/Norder6/Dir30000/Npix30889.jpg), its size is `119.7 kB`.

I have copied the failed test case below:

```
def test_fetch_read_write_jpg(self, tmpdir):
    meta = HipsTileMeta( ... )
    url = 'http://alasky.unistra.fr/2MASS/H/Norder6/Dir30000/Npix30889.jpg'
    tile = HipsTile.fetch(meta, url)

    filename = str(tmpdir / 'Npix30889.jpg')
    tile.write(filename)
    tile2 = HipsTile.read(meta, filename=filename)
    print(tile.data.shape)
    print(tile2.data.shape)

    assert tile == tile2
```

Here is the failed assertion:

> ----------------------------------Captured stdout call--------------------------------------
>
> (512, 512, 3)
>
> (512, 512, 3)
>
> False

The code involved with tile storing is shown below:

```
from scipy.misc import imsave
def write(self, filename: str = None) -> None:
    path = Path(filename) if filename else self.meta.full_path
    imsave(str(path), self.data)
```

I also tried saving the file using [PIL.Image](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html) library, using this code:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.fromarray(self.data)
image.save(str(path))
```

But, it produces the same results. I tried printing out the tile data at index `[0][0]` which came to be `[10, 10, 10]` for both cases. Also, I displayed the image using `matplotlib`, and the results were identical. But, I can't figure out the reason for the reduction in size / quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a [lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format.  If you write an image to a JPEG file and then read it back, you won't, in general, get back the same data.

For lossless image storage, you could use PNG.